# Should I let express or Elastic Beanstalk serve my static files?

Tags: express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a node express app running on AWS EB. I can let the express app serve my static files in the usual way by adding

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Or alternatively I can remove this and configure the static file within the EB configuration.

Any reason why I should choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Elastic Beanstalk, the Static Files section lets you configure the proxy server to serve static assets directly to the user without hitting your Node Express application. This improves the application performance by not utilizing the NodeJS thread to serve static files.

Also its better if you use AWS CloudFront infront of the Elastic Beanstalk, caching the static paths, to deliver the files from nearest AWS edge location to the user, to further improve the application performance.

Comment: ah great yeah that makes sense. The reason I ask is I have it setup like that... but for some reason whilst it's compressing my css it's not compressing my js - was thinking of serving from express and using compression there instead as that seems to work fine when I test locally.

Comment: @user1803975 Maybe your js is to small. Cloudfront starts compressing files when they are over 1kB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html